# зачем размещать фронтенд и бэкенд отдельно?

Tags: frontend, backend

я знаю несколько подходов к организации веб-приложения. мне не понятно зачем нужны некоторые из них. не могли бы привести практические реальные примеры, когда какой используется?

следующие решения мне понятны:

1. статический html (олдовый веб, gatsby, jekyll).
2. динамический html (server-side rendering). запрашиваю страницу, сервер собирает налету из кусков данных, шаблонов и других ассетов конечную html-страницу.
3. динамический html + ajax. пункт 2 + асинхронные запросы на сервер. получение данных, например , в формате json и добавление их на страницу. применять аякс тут можно по разному (получать html, json, jsonp и т.д.), но вопросов все же не вызывает.
4. динамический html + ajax + react. сервер собирает часть страницы, клиент получает html-файл и ассеты, среди которых есть бандл реакт-приложения. реакт-приложение инициализируется в одном из DOM-элементов. в браузере теперь работает реакт, рендерит компоненты, следит за состоянием и обновляет DOM.

а вот эти решения вызывают вопросы:

5. бэкенд (отдает только json, xml или другое) + spa. хостится на одном сервере, но как 2 разных приложения. общаются по сети.
6. бэкенд + spa, которые размещаются на разных серверах.

собственно, вопросы:

- я правильно понимаю, что когда хостят фронтенд отдельно, на самом деле это бэкенд-приложение (nginx, nodejs, другое), которое отдает index.html + js-бандл, собранный сборщиком?
- в каких случаях хостят эти 2 приложения(отдельно) на одном физическом сервере и когда хостят их на разных физических серверах?
- зачем разделять эти приложения, если js-бандл можно отдать с первым запросом к главной странице? (отдать страницу с одним лишь корневым элементом, куда будет инициализироваться app.js). получается тот же самый spa. в итоге 1 серверное приложение, которое отдает spa первым запросом и все это хостится на 1 физическом сервере.

Answer (score 1):

> я правильно понимаю, что когда хостят фронтенд отдельно, на самом деле
> это бэкенд-приложение (nginx, nodejs, другое), которое отдает
> index.html + js-бандл, собранный сборщиком?

В любом случае то, что отдаёт ресурс на запрос, будет приложением, запущенным на сервере. Например это будет упомянутый nginx или nodejs, или апач, или любая другая программа-http-сервер.

> в каких случаях хостят эти 2 приложения(отдельно) на одном физическом
> сервере и когда хостят их на разных физических серверах?

> зачем разделять эти приложения, если js-бандл можно отдать с первым
> запросом к главной странице?

Нет никакой нужды просто так разбивать приложение, если хватает апача или ноды, чтобы отдать страничку и обработать несколько запросов от неё. Разбивают, когда приложение не элементарное, и когда в этом есть потребность.

Приложению по большей части не важно, брать данные со "своего" сервера, или с "чужого". Кажется уютным когда всё вместе, но технически это не обязательно.

Программа-сервер может как отдавать статичные ресурсы, например html и бандл, так и обрабатывать запросы данных и отдавать например json. Часто бывает, что статичными ресурсами занимается одна программа (например nginx), а данные отдаёт другая (например node). Потому что для каждой задачи лучше подходит соответствующий инструмент.

Также причиной разделения на разные программы может быть разное назначение частей общего сервиса. Например если бэкенд отдаёт данные не только для сайта, но и для мобильного приложения, и для часов и бог знает чего ещё, он может быть сделан отдельно.

Бандл и html могут храниться на серверах, оптимизированных на отдачу статичных ресурсов, например CDN. А обработку данных могут вынести на отдельный сервер, предназначенный для обработки данных. У этих двух частей разный подход и разная тарификация за ресурсы, поэтому может быть не выгодно и не удобно держать их вместе. Таких частей может быть много. И могут не все принадлежать одной компании, а использоваться по подписке или быть бесплатными.

Есть ещё подход разбивания монолитного сервиса на части. Чтобы по отдельности разрабатывать, поддерживать и обновлять эти части.